# How to programmatically display all images in a page bundle

Tags: javascript, hugo

I want to display all the jpg images in a directory.

My leaf bundle structure is like this:

```
site/
-> content/
   -> mypage/
      -> index.md
         images/
         -> john.jpg
            bryan.jpg
            mary.jpg
```

I don't feel like this is a very strange or unusual use case, so I'm not sure why the documentation doesn't provide a good example.

I need to know what to write in the index.md file to display images.
This is what I have so far.

````
---
title: "Pictures"
date: 2019-01-10T19:50:24-05:00
draft: true
resources:
- name: jpg-file-:counter
  src: 'images/**.jpg'
---
## Check out my page!
### I want to display all the .jpg in ```images/```

{{ with .Resources.ByType "image" }}
  // I really wish I could get a console log in here
  // this feels like shooting into the dark
{{ end }}
````

Please provide links if possible to some actual code examples. I have not been able to find many examples of Page Resources and Page Bundle implementation. It is not well addressed in tutorials.

Comment: Seem like [this page](https://gohugo.io/templates/files/) has examples that could be modified to do what you want.

Comment: you can use `{{ printf "%#v" . }}` in your `with` loop to see what is actually being passed.

Comment: It doesn't want to interpret anything - I still just get verbatim text like this: Pictures
Check out my page!
I want to display all the .jpg in images/

{{ with .Resources.ByType “image” }} {{ printf “%#v” . }} {{ end }}

Comment: I think within a markdown content page you want to use a [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/). In that shortcode file, e.g., layouts/shortcodes/list_images.html, is where you would put the logic you have above. See https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/ If you want to embed the logic directly in the content file see the Inline Shortcodes section on that last link.